# ASP.NET MVC 4 Not populating dropdownlist from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I am new in ASP.NET MVC 4. I want to populate dropdownlist by taking values from database. But dropdownlist doesn't populating with data. I am not getting where I am wrong. On the basis of following link I have develop my code. Is anybody have any other better way so kindly suggest. I am using code first approach with Razor engine. 
[Click here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/%22here%22)

My Controller class :

```
public class iRegController : Controller
{
    private iRegDBContext l_oDbBO = new iRegDBContext();  

    // GET: /iReg/

    public ActionResult PopulatejQgrid()
    {
        var BOList = l_oDbBO
                     .BO
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(d => new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value = d.Id.ToString(),
                             Text = d.Name + "[ " + d.Code + " ]"
                         });
        ViewBag.BOData = new SelectList(BOList, "Value", "Text"); 
        return View();
    }
}
```

My Model class :

```
public class BO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class iRegDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BO> BO { get; set; }
}
```

My cshtml class :

```
@model MvciReg.Models.BO

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PopulatejQgrid";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        BO : 

        @Html.DropDownList("BOData")
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Updated :** My table name is BO and Database name is iReg. And my connectionstring is

```
 <add name="iRegDBContext"
  connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=iReg;User ID=**;Password=****;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your list as a model to Html.DropDownList like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BOData", (SelectList)ViewBag.BOData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try another way:

```
public ActionResult PopulatejQgrid()
    {
        var myList = new List<SelectListItems>();

        var list = l_oDbBO.BO.ToList();

        var items = from g in list
                     select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value = g.Id.ToString(),
                             Text = g.Name + "[ " + g.Code + " ]"
                         };

        foreach(var item in items)
           myList.add(item);

        ViewBag.BOData = myList ; 
        return View();
    }
```

In you View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Booo", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BOData)
```

Comment: Its is showing red underline under `Select new`  and if I change it `select` it shows red underline under `.ToList()`.. What should I do this???

Comment: Still it's not working.... I have updated my question... If you want any more extra info about my code let me know....

Comment: @Rahul Try to return your List of values without dropdown just to see if the issue is in db connection or in populating dropdown

Comment: @ Andrey.Gubal : Its not giving any error in while connection. I think problem is in deferred query execution. Its not returning single value. I just want to ask that in my BO table there is one more column OrgId but here in this code its no use of this column that's why I have not mentioned in Model class. Is this problem because of this extra column....???

Comment: @Rahul No, it is not a problem. If you return your values without dropdown do you see them on your page?

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
@Html.DropDownList element expect a collection of type IEnumerable to populate the DropDownList. So rewriting your query such as:

```
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BOList = l_oDbBO
                 .BO.Select(d => d)
                 .AsEnumerable)
                 .Select(d => new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = d.Id.ToString(),
                         Text = d.Name + "[ " + d.Code + " ]"
                     });
```

should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult PopulateJQgrid()
{
   ViewBag.BOData = new SelectList(l_oDbBO.BO, "Name", "Name");
   return View();
}
```

In your View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BOData")
```

-- SelectList(Context.Table, "the ColumnName of the attribute that you used as value", "the ColumnName of the attribute that you used as the text of your dropdownlist")

:)

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: I want to bind two columns(Name & code) of BO table to DataTextField of Datadropdownlist. But my code is not retrieving Data from database. I tried your code but its not populating value in dropdown... so please suggest some code which will retrieve data from database and bind data to dropdown as per my above logic.